# Multiple clients "connect" to server, but 1 client not running "properly"

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server

Basically I have a server that connects to multiple clients, but only the first client that connects to the server is the one that works properly. I'm basically not sure how to make it work for multiple clients... I tried a thread method, but that didn't seem to work. Please advise.

Comment: What exactly not working properly ?

Comment: It works properly with one client but when I have another client running, the first client works while the second doesn't. The client that runs second gives me the same message when it is supposed to give varying messages (i.e. token received or TRY AGAIN). The second client always gives me TRY AGAIN.

Comment: I can't see "try again in your code."
upload somewhere the full client and server , post the link in you question, and I will take a look soon.